# Is Cross dressing allowed on purim

Tags: purim, tznius-modesty, women, men-male, clothing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is cross-dressing permitted on Purim and if so why?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14479/is-cross-dressing-permitted-on-purim-and-if-so-why)

Normally cross dressing is against Halacha is it allowed on Purim?