# Why is crossdressing permitted on Purim if it's forbidden without condition?

Tags: halacha, clothing, purim, lo-yilbash

Why do some rabbinical authorities authorize cross-dressing on Purim if it's unconditionally forbidden?

Comment: −1, as this question makes no sense to me. How can you say some rabbinical authorities authorize something in the same breath as saying it's unconditionally forbidden? If you're saying it's unconditionally forbidden, then those who authorize it are not your authorities; if authorities permit it, then obviously the ban is not unconditional. Do you mean to ask [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14479) instead?

Comment: @msh210, that might be my fault; there's another question about cross-dressing where the answer seems to be that cross-dressing is unconditionally forbidden, then somebody raised Purim in the comments, then this question got asked.  In trying to clarify the title I might have introduced a problem.  Anyway, all that said, it sounds like a dupe of the question you linked to.

Comment: @msh210 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22959/what-was-the-point-of-the-tree-of-life#comment53239_22959

Comment: @msh210, Yeah I agree with Monica.  It seems more like the question is worded poorly rather than being a bad question itself. I agree also, though, that it is definitely a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @Daniel Arg you are _so_ close to having a close vote.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, not your fault, the title you created matched the text of the question.