# Can one wear their clothing backwards on Purim?

Tags: halacha, clothing, purim

I've seen many people on Purim who wear their clothing inside out, in the spirit of ונהפוך הוא. Yet the Mechaber writes explicitly (SA OC 2:3):

> ידקדק בחלוקו ללובשו כדרכו שלא יהפוך הפנימי לחוץ
>
> He should be particular with his cloak to wear it properly, that the inside not be turned outside.

Now, [crossdressing may be permissible on Purim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14479/), depending on your posek and rationale. I'd imagine turning one's garment inside-out, which is simply a matter of looking respectable (Mishnah Berurah ad. loc.), is a much lesser prohibition and so should be permitted. Nevertheless, are there any sources which explicitly address this one way or another?

Comment: Cf Shaatnez on Purim

Comment: @JoelK Is that discussed anywhere? I can’t imagine that that would be permitted; the rationale to permit לא ילבש doesn’t extend.

Comment: Shaatnez derabannan https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.696.8?lang=he

Answer (score 1):

ידקדק means it's not an Issur. key word he should. The Mishan Brurah says the reason is that people would think that your crazy for wearing your clothes inside out and you would be demeaning yourself. Based on this reason of the Mishnah Brurah I believe that on Purim people would assume that you are doing this for the spirit of the holiday thus making the reason irrelevant.

MISHNAH BRURAH ON SIMAN 2 MISHNAH BRURAH 4

לחוץ - ויראו תפירות המגונות ואמרי החלוק ויתגנה בעיני הבריות ואם לא נזהר והפך אם ת"ח הוא צריך לפושטו ולחזור ללבשו כדרכו שלא יהיה בכלל משניאי ח"ו ושאר כל אדם אין צריך ולתפלה אפילו כל אדם צריך לפשטו וללבשו כדרכו שראוי אז להדר בגדיו כמבואר בסימן צ"א. טוב שישים שני צדי המלבוש ביד ימינו וילבש הימין ואח"כ השמאל ויכוין כי הכל נכלל בימין ומן הימין בא לשמאל. כתב הרמב"ם מלבוש ת"ח יהיה מלבוש נאה ונקי ואסור לו שימצא בבגדו כתם או שמנונית וכיוצא בהם. ולא ילבש לא מלבוש שרים שהכל מסתכלים בהם ולא מלבוש עניים שהוא מבזה את לובשיו אלא בגדים בינונים נאים ע"ש עוד: